# Do I really need two policy servers for two different silverlight applications?

Tags: .net, sockets, silverlight-3.0, network-programming

I have a client-server Silverlight application, which is use Socets. I have server appliaction on may computer(Win Form application) and client applucation as web site(Silverlight application). I use policy server which open port 943.
Everything works fine on this application.
But now I need to write another client-server application. Server for that application olso use port 943 for policy connection. When I try to run this 2 server applications on the same compyeter an excepten is thrown which says that only one application can work on port 943.
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to write separate policy server application and run it before your main server application.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me, and I'm not sure how it got marked as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different port for the second server.

Alternatively, use the REUSEADDR socket option, but [that's not a good idea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740621(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: I can not use other port. The only port for policy server is 943.

Comment: @Samvel: There is no other way around it - it's a limitation of TCP itself that you just have to live with.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the idea of a policy server to grant access to multiple applications?

Answer (score 0):

Like Nikolai said, this is a non sensical question.

The answer is:

Just run one policy server! I am going to edit the question to reflect this.